# Dropzone area in frontend acf_form to upload multiple images to new post

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload, advanced-custom-fields, dropzone.js

I'm currently working on a frontend form for users to create a post on our site. The form is set up using acf_form and all of the actual fields work. Along with various text inputs, the users should be able to upload both a number of images and a number of pdf files to the post. This can of course be achieves using for example a repeater field with basic image and file uploader, but that's not a very user-friendly approach, I feel. Therefore I've added dropzone areas (http://www.dropzonejs.com/) where they can drop the fields. However, when I post the form, the files array is empty - I think the problem is the url I'm setting as the option for the dropzone options is wrong, but I can't figure out where to post for it to work properly.

Here are some relevant parts of my code:

```
$extrafields =
'<div class="canvas" id="image--canvas">
<div class="dz-message">Klik eller træk billeder hertil for at tilføje</div>
</div>
<div class="canvas" id="file--canvas">
<div class="dz-message">Klik eller træk filer hertil for at tilføje</div>
</div>';

$formoptions = array(
    'post_id'       => 'new_post',
    'new_post'      => array(
        'post_type'     => 'projekt',
        'post_status'   => 'publish'
    ),
    'submit_value'  => 'Indstil projekt',
    'post_title' => true,
    'field_groups' => array( 
        'group_58329d09a0e22', 
        'group_584ed2ee82818', 
    ),
    'post_content' => true, 
    'wrap_field_groups' => true,
    'uploader' => 'basic',
    'html_before_fields' => $extrafields,
);
```

The actual form is added to the page template with:

```
acf_form($formoptions);
```

(I move the dropzones from the beginning of the form to the appropriate places using JS)

Dropzone constructs:

```
$("#image--canvas").dropzone({
    url: window.location.origin + window.location.pathname,
    clickable: true,
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    parallelUploads: 100,
    maxFileSize: 6,
    maxFiles: 8,
    acceptedFiles: 'image/*',
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    dictCancelUpload: 'Fjern fil',
});
```

When I intercept the acf/validate_save_post, the $_FILES array is empty. Same with acf/pre_save_post. My plan of attact was to intercept the files from the dropzones and then manually upload and add them to the relevant fields for the new post. But as long as the array is empty, this is rather difficult.

Any suggestions on how to get this to work are greatly appreciated. Or other approaches as well. My main purpose is just to allow the (not logged in) user to upload multiple files from the frontend form in a nice way.

[Screenshot here for reference of how I would like it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsovJ.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Does your form have the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute?

Comment: Looks like Dropzone uploads files directly after dropping via ajax, so you'll have to manage the uploads separately and then attach them to your ACF fields manually afterwards.

Comment: @tobiv Yes, that's added automatically by the acf_form function

Comment: @tobiv According to the documentation it's possible to turn the asynchronous upload off by using the `autoProcessQueue: false` - so I assumed it would then be possible to just include it along with the rest of the form element, when posting everything?

Comment: I see, but you then have to call `.processQueue()` yourself. I don't think you get regular file inputs otherwise, but I'm not very familiar with it...